# Isomorphism between Tangent Sheaf and Cotangent Sheaf

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, tangent-bundle, k3-surfaces

I'm studying K3 surfaces and I often encountered the fact that the tangent sheaf $\mathcal{T}$ is isomorphic to the sheaf of differentials $\Omega$. Why is this true? I guess this follows from the triviality of the canonical bundle (?).

Comment: Locally this works just as @KReiser described. This also works globally on a K3 surface because we have a holomorphic non-degenerate $2$-form $\sigma$, and contracting with that gives an isomorphism $\mathcal T \to \Omega^1$ by $\xi \mapsto (\eta \mapsto \sigma(\xi, \eta) )$.

Comment: @KReiser How does triviality of the canonical bundle imply $\Omega_X\cong \mathcal{O}_X^n$? If this were true then $\chi(X) =0$, which is certainly not the case.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter sorry, commented before coffee this morning - the correct statement here is  that for a locally free sheaf $F$ of rank $r$, the multiplication map $\bigwedge^n F \otimes \bigwedge^{r-n} F \to \bigwedge^r F$ is a perfect pairing, i.e. it induces an isomorphism $\bigwedge^n F \cong (\bigwedge^{n-r} F)^\vee \otimes \bigwedge^r F$. Plugging in $F=\Omega_X$, $r=2$, $n=1$, we get $\Omega \cong \mathcal{T}$ as $\bigwedge^2 \Omega_X\cong\omega_X\cong\mathcal{O}_X$. Apologies for the error!